# typeerror when printing tx events

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

I have this solidity function:

```
function newContract(uint[] memory numbers, address[] memory addresses, string[] memory names) 
                    external authorized payable returns (address){
uint256 bnbAmount = msg.value;
uint256 bnbFee = 10 * 10**15;
bnbAmount = bnbAmount.sub(bnbFee);
address _aBot = makeAntiBot();
IBot anti = IBot(_aBot);
emit Creation(_aBot);
address _template = deploy(numbers, addresses, names,_aBot);
emit Creation(_template);
test = _template;
anti.addContract(_template);
liquidAdd(test, 0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209, bnbAmount);


return _template;
```

}

it generates new conntract, I made this python code to automate that

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
import time 
ganache_url = 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))
account_1 = '0x16A5Ba2015c6AF84eA81c4500E1E11984cBAFA5D'
private_key1 = ''

#get the nonce.  Prevents one from sending the transaction twice
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_1)

ca= Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x4927d4DcCeD20A94F128efb4927662B26df016b3')
abi = json.loads('[ { "inputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountBNB", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amountCoin", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "AutoLiquify", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "creation", "type": "address" } ], "name": "Creation", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" } ], "name": "OwnershipTransferred", "type": "event" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "adr", "type": "address" } ], "name": "authorize", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "clearStuckBalance", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "numbers", "type": "uint256[]" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "addresses", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "string[]", "name": "names", "type": "string[]" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "antiBot", "type": "address" } ], "name": "deploy", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "adr", "type": "address" } ], "name": "isAuthorized", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "account", "type": "address" } ], "name": "isOwner", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "_token", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "_newOwner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "liquidAdd", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "makeAntiBot", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "numbers", "type": "uint256[]" }, { "internalType": "address[]", "name": "addresses", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "string[]", "name": "names", "type": "string[]" } ], "name": "newContract", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "router", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "contract IDEXRouter", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "test", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address payable", "name": "adr", "type": "address" } ], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "adr", "type": "address" } ], "name": "unauthorize", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "_bot", "type": "address" } ], "name": "updateBotDeploy", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "_template", "type": "address" } ], "name": "updateTemplate", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "receive" } ]')
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=ca, abi=abi)


#build a transaction in a dictionary
params = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'from': account_1,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.02, 'ether'),
    'gas': 7000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('11', 'gwei')
}

func = token_contract.functions.newContract([1,1000000,60,50,40,30,50,70,5,3,20,40,6,96,1661668129000,5,3,3], ["0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209","0xE9d39D5b1EEb143FADA974980F17a273Ef8e2209"], 
["hrissa","TESTF"]
)


tx = func.buildTransaction(params)
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=private_key1)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print(tx_hash)
print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

I want to get the event logs from the tx, so I tried this :

```
logs = token_contract.events.Creation().processReceipt(tx_hash)
print(logs)
```

but it returned this error:

byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

any solution?

tx hash : https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x5eae5699e132cde33e25430129587d8d73d007fed71529507e2288b37cecd815

Comment: tx hash : https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x5eae5699e132cde33e25430129587d8d73d007fed71529507e2288b37cecd815